# All-round solution for making video calls and screen sharing cross platform

Tags: cordova, cross-platform, webrtc, video-conferencing

I'm looking for an all round solution for making video calls (with multiple users at the same time), screen sharing (on the same moment when making a video/audio call), (3D) navigation(walking to a destination while following an arrow on the screen) and push notifications. I want to build a cross-platform (web)application with all these functions. My first idea was to build a webapplication. But I then had to use webRTC, which is not supported in all major browsers and/or operating systems.

I searched for a solution, but I think it’s really confusing and all the solutions that I found were platform specific and had most of the time limitations. Does someone know a way/party/plug-in/service or a combination to achieve this? My idea was to use PhoneGap to make my application cross-platform. But I don't think I can develop all those functions with PhoneGap. Could someone please advise me? I looked into WebRTC but I'm not sure which functions are available in which OS in combination with PhoneGap. My research gave me an understanding that most services/companies/plug-ins are not available for Windows Phone. I definitely don't want to reinvent the wheel. I don’t have any experience with PhoneGap. But from what I’ve read, it looks very promising.  Should I create a ‘WebRTC’ server for handling multiple connections? Or should I connect third parties to solve this? Such as PubNub or FlashPhoner? Or is a ‘WebRTC’ server not required? 
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: software or api requests are off topic for SO as they can be very opinionated.

Comment: Thank you @BenjaminTrent. I'm new to SO, and trying to follow the rules and stay on topic. How do I have to formulate this question? Or are these kind of questions not welcome on SO? I'm just searching for a solution for my problem. Maybe somebody has already experience with this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The solution can not be implemented without installation of an additional software by end-user.

First reason - ios does not support WebRTC in its Safari browser.
Second reason - IE and Safari does not support WebRTC.
Third reason - Flash does not support screensharing natively.

So, the possible solution is an MCU server which supports either WebRTC and Flash via RTMP, or RTMFP and a plugin for screen capturing or webrtc plugin that supports screen sharing.
As i know Adobe Air supports screen sharing, but Flash does not support.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Nick! I'm happy to read that there maybe is a possible solution. I'm new with MCU servers, so I have to explore that.